# RichTextBlock truncates content when double new lines are used but not triple

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I have some XML...

```
...
<body>
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
    ...
</body>
...
```

I parse the XML into a string such that a double new-line is inserted after each P element is appended to the string...

```
foreach (XElement e in element.Element("body").Descendants("p"))
{
    try
    {
        item.Content += e.Value + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    catch { }
}
```

The Content property of the item is later bound to the Content Run in the RichTextBlock element of the Item Detail Page template available in Visual Studio 2012. At this point I notice some odd behaviour.

Some items will truncate their text at the end of the first column and add ellipsis where I would expect the text to overflow into a new column. When I change the resolution of the simulator the previously truncated item displays correctly and a different item will become truncated. If I switch the resolution back then the previous item truncates again.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrTqP.png

Even more strangely if I change the parsing code to insert a triple new-line everything overflows as I would expect.

Initially I assumed that the RichTextBlock was miscalculating the need to overflow into a new column but this does not explain the ellipsis it adds nor the fact that it always truncates at the end of a word.

Here is the XAML for my RichTextBox...

```
<RichTextBlock x:Name="richTextBlock" Width="560" Style="{StaticResource ItemRichTextStyle}" IsTextSelectionEnabled="False">

    <Paragraph>
        <Run FontSize="26.667" FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run FontWeight="Normal" Text="{Binding PublicationDate, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeString}}"/>
    </Paragraph>

    <Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <Image x:Name="image" MaxHeight="480" Margin="0,20,0,10" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding LargeImage, Converter={StaticResource ImageLocation}, ConverterParameter=news}" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
        </InlineUIContainer>
    </Paragraph>

    <Paragraph>
        <Run FontWeight="SemiLight" Text="{Binding Content}"/>
    </Paragraph>

</RichTextBlock>
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can prevent the RichTextBlock from automatically truncating its content?

Comment: Fair point. I thought it was fairly obvious but I guess not. I have clarified :)

Comment: Do you have RichTextOverflow control ?

Comment: I do. I'm using the Item Detail page generated by Visual Studio 2012.